# Differences between rds and RData

Tags: r

In my R global environment I have several objects among data frames, lists and models. When added up their size amounts to 450 Mb. If I save them as Rdata, it reduces the size to around 350 Mb, but If I instead put them all in a list and save them as rds, I get 56 Mb. Why do I get very different compression sizes saving the same objects?

Comment: How did you save each out (the specific R calls)?

Comment: The Rdata I saved with  save.image("file.rda"), the rds I save using saveRDS(list,"file.rds").

Comment: Thx. `save.image()` is really `save(list = names(.GlobalEnv))` (I left out the file name params). How did you make your `list` in the `saveRDS()` call? And, are there other elements in your global environment `save.image()` might have picked up?

Comment: I made the list by using list<-mget(ls()). I don't think that there are other elements in the global environment that save.image() might have picked up.

Comment: Well, at a minimum you picked up `".Random.seed` (the ~equiv call wld have used `ls(all.names = TRUE)`). One way to see all the names saved is to do `((load("file.rda"))`. The reason I'm focusing on possible hidden env elements is that both saving methods default to compression level 6 and use similar serialization code underneath (at the C level).

Comment: Yes, you are right I picked up ".Random.seed" but nothing else. I checked the size of ".Random.seed"  and it's 104 bytes.